# What are the scalability and performance limitations relating to many branches in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, branch

My team is considering doing branch-per-task development in TFS 2010. We are thinking of using shelvesets for small tasks (1-3 days) and creating new branches for anything larger (4 days to 2 months). Once development is complete on the branch it will be merged to main and deleted (not destroyed). Typically it will be only one developer working on a particular branch.

Does anyone have experience working on a project using TFS 2010 with many branches. How did it work? Were there any server performance issues as the number of branches grew? Does it affect the performance of the VS IDE at all?

There are already many answers out there relating to questions such as "TFS sucks at merging and is crushing my soul, what can I do?" and "Why would anyone ever use TFS when x, y, and z are available?" Please try to keep your answers relating to server performance and usability of the system in the presence of a large number of branches.

Here is some background with my history of branching. The project I worked on previously used a branch-per-task strategy with ClearCase and it worked very well. Branch creation was tied to both the defect tracking and build system. Developers completed units of work each in their own branch. The lifetime of each branch varied from a day up to a couple of months. At the end of each task the code was merged into the main integration branch. This was a large project and after approximately 10 years of development the system has over 10,000 branches. ClearCase is able to handle this volume of branching quite well (except when viewing popular files in the Version Tree Browser, load time could be slow).

Comment: Do some searches on "Feature Branching".  We have used it successfully in my shop.  One important factor is that you want for the type of work going on in your branches to be enough of a separate concern that you don't have tons of merge conflicts.  My advice would be don't concentrate on a branch per person, but a branch per feature.  So you would have a "Widget Data Services" branch, but not a "James" branch. -- branches by name are considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the model you describe is a Branch by Feature, this is the model that the Dev Div of Microsoft uses to develop the Visual Studio product family, so you can tell it scales pretty well with TFS.

I recommend you to read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/teams_wit_tools/archive/2008/04/03/how-microsoft-devdiv-uses-tfs-chapter-2-feature-crews.aspx) and you can read the [Branching Guide V2](http://tfsbranchingguideii.codeplex.com/) to get more information.

As for the merging, the topic was pretty well covered here and on the web, in my opinion it doesn't suck when you use it correctly (and without the default merge tool).